# What would be the Slater's determinant of an excited state?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

**Setup**

Introducing this spinorbital notation:

\begin{align}
\Psi_1=\chi_{(r1)}\alpha_{(\omega1)}  &= 1 \\
\Psi_1=\chi_{(r1)}\beta_{(\omega1)}  &= \bar{1}
\end{align}

and the Slater's determinant, for a system of two electrons, is:

\begin{align}
|\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot \left| 
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \bar{1}  \\
2 & \bar{2}  \\
\end{array} 
\right| = |1\bar{2}-\bar{1}2\rangle
\end{align}

**Question**

Based on the example, what would be the Slater's determinant representation for an excited state like $\Psi_a^r$ (*i.e.* with parallel spins like: $|\bar{1}\bar{1}\rangle$ or $|\bar{1}\bar{2}\rangle$) and $\Psi_{ab}^{rs}$ (feel free to use any number) ?